# How to set cookie with chrome extension API for subdomain?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, subdomain

The [chrome.cookies.set](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set) API receive `url` as one of its parameter, from which cookie's `domain` and `path` is calculated.

For example, if `url`'s value is `https://stackoverflow.com`, then `domain` is `stackoverflow.com`, while `path` is `/`.

The issue is, how to set a cookie with **stackoverflow**'s subdomain: `.stackoverflow.com`. In other words, we want to have a cookie whose `domain` value is `.stackoverflow.com`

I've tried two approaches, none of them work.

1. `{ url: https//*.stackoverflow.com }`
2. `{ url: https//.stackoverflow.com }`

Comment: Specify `domain: 'stackoverflow.com', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com'`.

Comment: Doesn't work @wOxxOm, The current cookie won't be edited, but A new cookie whose domain is `stackoverflow.com` will be inserted. This is not the desired behavior. :(

Comment: Delete the current cookie and set the new one?

Comment: Yes I think about this strategy. But somehow can't set `domain` value to be a subdomain `.stackoverflow.com`. Its value is always `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: There's no need for the leading dot when you use `domain`. It already applies to all sub-domains.

Comment: Yes it does. I found the stackoverflow's related topic here. 
Posting this for future reference.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: CảnhToànNguyễn have you been able to set the cookie from Chrome extension? `domain` param is not documented in the API. And it does not work for me in Chrome v91

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is actually setting a cookie for all subdomains if you want to set `.stackoverflow.com`.

From my experience the API method [chrome.cookies.set](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/#method-set) will set cookies for both: domain and all subdomains, when you specify the domain:

```js
chrome.cookies.set({ 
  url: 'https//stackoverflow.com/?sth', 
  domain: 'stackoverflow.com', 
  name: 'some_cookie', 
  value: 'cookie_value' 
})
```

Will result in two cookies created for the page:

1. `some_cookie:cookie_value:stackoverflow.com`
2. `some_cookie:cookie_value:.stackoverflow.com`

To set only a cookie for the main domain you should set URL and let Chrome set the domain based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{ url: "https//stackoverflow.com", domain: ".stackoverflow.com" }`

Tested on Google Chrome version `107.0.5304.88`

if you omit the domain, then the domain will be host-only like `stackoverflow.com`, and if you specified the domain, the domain will always be a subdomain like `.stackoverflow.com`

see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/#method-set

We can distinguish between domain and subdomain by the `domain` field in `chrome.cookies.set`, but we can't distinguish them in `chrome.cookies.remove`, because it only accept `url` `name` and `storageId` but no `domain` field. If we use `chrome.cookies.remove`, it will remove both domain and subdomain.

So if we want to remove only one of them, we can use `chrome.cookies.set` like this:

```js
chrome.cookies.set({ ...cookie, domain: cookie.domain.startsWith('.') ? domain : undefined, expirationDate: 0 })
```